# Interconnect IT Search Replace DB HTTP Issue

Tags: database, wordpress, search, replace

Is it just me being a silly goose, but is this Search-Replace Tool still working on `http` servers?

`https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB`

I have been using this for years, but haven't for a about 2-3 months , now all of a sudden my http urls are automatically forwarding `http://example.com/Search-Replace-DB/` to `https://example.com/Search-Replace-DB/` ? Or is this a setting implemented on new chrome browser version and other browser versions? (does the same thing on other browsers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind this is not the case. I had a redirection plugin which was forcing https which was causing the issue.

Thanks